# Unable to insert current_timestamp in MySQL using c# Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, datetime, mysql-workbench

Sample code snippet:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Created_Date", MySqlDbType.Datetime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Declaration in Stored Procedure "Created_Date DATETIME"

```
error code: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Created_Date", MySqlDbType.Timestamp)).Value = DateTime.Now;
```